# Is « Does exist at least one function $u$ such that $f(u(0)) \ne g(u(0))$? » an NP problem? or a P problem?

Tags: np, decision-problem, p-vs-np

$f$ and $g$ being known functions.

We suppose that the problem is solvable.

To me, for the moment, this question, if a decision problem it is or can be, is more an NP rather than a P problem, because if it was a P problem, we would have to answer it in polynomial time, and so test every $u$ function in a single polynomial time, which is impossible?

So, is it possible to say, because the instance is infinitely numerous, it is not in P?

If exist at least one $u$ function that solve the problem, and with which you can check that the answer problem is « yes » in polynomial time, is the problem in NP?

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: You may have answered. It may be a silly question, but if there is no input, there is no P or NP problem right? Is it possible to consider the question as a decision problem with the function u as the input?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that $f:A\to B$ and $g:A\to B$ for some (known) sets $A$ and $B$ and that, given a set $C\ni0$ we are to find a function $u:C\to A$ such that $f(u(0))=g(u(0))$. Of course, this is just the same as asking for an element $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=g(a)$ (consider, for instance, the constant function $u(x)=a$). This, in turn, is the same as asking if $f(A)\cap g(A)$ is empty or not.

But this isn't even decidable. Consider the function $f(n)$ which is 1 if n is the binary representation of a Lean proof of the Riemann hypothesis and 0 otherwise, and the function $g(n)=1.$ Now replace $f$ with the undecidable function of your choice.

So definitely not in NP.

Comment: If you’re asking something else, please clarify. Otherwise, if I’ve understood your ask, consider accepting the answer so others know this is what you meant.